# Delay drawing of a WindowsFormsHost?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Is there a way to delay the drawing of a WindowsFormsHost?  It's hosted in WPF.

It hosts a COM object which is an ESRI ArcEngine AxTocControl.  Visually it looks like a table of contents tab.

I'm removing a number of objects from the table of contents and adding a different objects in a single function.

When I remove an object, the TOC control blinks and removes and object,  then I add an object, and it blinks and adds an object.  Since I am adding and removing 20 objects, its blinking 20 times.  I would like to delay the drawing -- do all my operations -- and then resume drawing -- hopefully i will only have 1 or two blinks / flashes.

So to summarize, is there a function or technique (I don't care how hacky it is) to delay the drawing of a WindowsFormHost - let some things execute - and then resume drawing?

Comment: If you feel my answer as it stands is satisfactory, please remember to award the bounty before it expires. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Jon sorry I thought I had done that Friday

Comment: Thanks! This is actually the first full bounty ever I got -- was frustrated a few times :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can create your own `WindowsFormsHost` subclass for this specific scenario and override [`WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.wndproc.aspx). From there, you can decide to silently ignore (by not calling `base.WndProc`) all [drawing-related messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162761%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) as long as a "suppress updates" condition holds.

The condition you can implement any way you like, e.g. set up a public `PausePainting()` / `ResumePainting()` method in your class that sets a boolean field.

You will also have to remember to repaint when e.g. `ResumePainting()` is called, because you don't want your control to *never* update.

In the end it's not going to be as simple as A-B-C, but the concept is sound so it should work out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread.Sleep(0) to introduce a delay.

Answer (score 0):

You could try processing everything, adding them one by one to a list, then add the whole list at one time.

```
myWpfControl.Clear();
List<EsriModel> items = new List<EsriModel>();
// Code to populate your items
myWpfControl.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

Could it be that simple? That should prevent your WPF Control from flickering as you add them one by one.